# Pairing in two player game with firebase in android?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, multiplayer

I am trying to implement a two player game in android using firebase(for realtime pairing).

On firebase, i have set up a node representing active players. And on each client i have a childEventListener to listen to any changes on the players node.

Suppose

1. Initially there is only one player (Player A).
2. Then 3 more players(B,C and D) got added (At the SAME TIMESTAMP).

Then, on client side
1. Each of 4 players will get notified about the changes in the node through childEventListener.

Now, What i want to achieve is "UNIQUE PAIRING" i.e I should be able to generate 2 pairs from these 4 players. (Of course, one player can't be in both the pairs)

I have written code to pair two players in a transaction block so that no two players get paired with the same player.

```
private void attachActivePlayersEventListener() {
        Log.i(TAG, "attachActivePlayersEventListener");
        if (activePlayersEventListener == null) {

            activePlayersEventListener = new ChildEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                    searchPlayer(dataSnapshot);
                    Log.i("PLAYER_ADDED ", dataSnapshot.getValue(Player.class).getName());

                }

                @Override
                public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                    searchPlayer(dataSnapshot);
                    Log.i("PLAYER_CHANGED ", dataSnapshot.getValue(Player.class).getName());
                }

                @Override
                public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                }

            };
            mActivePlayersDbRef.addChildEventListener(activePlayersEventListener);
        }
    }

private void searchPlayer(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        if(mPlayer.getState().equals(PlayerState.ACTIVE)) { // if the current user is active
            final String oppKey = dataSnapshot.getKey();
            Player oppPlayer = dataSnapshot.getValue(Player.class);

            if (oppPlayer.getState().equals(PlayerState.ACTIVE)
                    && !oppKey.equals(pushId)) { // if the opponent chosen is not the current user

                DatabaseReference oppRef = mActivePlayersDbRef.child(oppKey);
                oppRef.runTransaction(new Transaction.Handler() {

                    @Override
                    public Transaction.Result doTransaction(MutableData mutableData) {
                        Player player2 = mutableData.getValue(Player.class);
                        if (player2 == null) {
                            return Transaction.success(mutableData);
                        }
                        mActivePlayersDbRef.child(pushId).child("state").setValue(PlayerState.PLAYING);
                        mActivePlayersDbRef.child(oppKey).child("state").setValue(PlayerState.PLAYING);

                        return Transaction.success(mutableData);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, boolean b, DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        Log.d("PAIRING", "pairing:onComplete:" + databaseError);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
```

My DOUBT is

1. Is this the correct way of pairing?
2. What happens when PlayerA tries to pair up with PlayerB, PlayerB tries to pair up with PlayerC and PlayerC tries to pair up with PlayerD and finally PlayerD tries to pair up with PlayerA(In a CYCLIC way). How to make sure this case doesn't happen?

Note that in Doubt2, I am not taking care of the condition where two players try to pair up with the same player. (As transaction block will ensure that it won't happen, I guess :/ ).

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is difficult to do correctly and safely.  It's better to let a backend service do this matching so that the clients don't all have to figure out how to agree with each other somehow.

You can use [Cloud Functions for Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/) to write a [database trigger](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events) that responds to changes in your database.  One strategy would be for clients to push data into a location in the database to indicate their *intent* to be matched.  Then, when a function triggers on those writes, it can check to see if there are other suitable players to be matched, and write more data into the database to set up the game.  The clients will also need a way to listen for the game starting up after they have been matched.  This is still all very much non-trivial, but a lot easier than putting the logic in the clients.

Comment: Hey @Doug, I explored cloud functions for firebase a bit but still having the same concurrency issue. So suppose i wrote a cloud function "pairMe()" which gets triggered every time a player is added to the "IWannaPlay" node in firebase. Now if 50 players come at a single timestamp, 50 instances of the function pairMe() would get triggered at that instant and again all those problem which i mentioned in my question may arise.  

The basic problem i am facing is "Given a stream of players, how could i generate unique pairs (using firebase tools if possible) ?"

Comment: Use a transaction to ensure serialized access to a particular location in your database.